# How to round all numeric columns of a DataTable to 2 decimal places?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

```
 Dim DS_LASSummary As New DataSet
  DS_LASSummary = Nbfcweb.GetReceivablesForLAS(txtLASAcctno.Text, CmbBankEntryType.Text.Trim)
```

Now DS_LASSummary can have n number of numeric columns. I want to round each one of the numeric columns to two decimal places. I can not hardcode the names or index of columns.

I don't think datatype can be changed of a particular datatable. So what are my options?

Comment: You need to do that in the query or procedure from where this datatable is filling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on this, can't you use Math.Round
Something like below might work. Not sure on syntax too.

```
foreach (DataRow drRow in DS_LASSummary.Rows)
```

```
{
    for(int i = 0; i < DS_LASSummary.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        int rowValue;

        if (int.TryParse(drRow[i].ToString(), out rowValue))
        {

            drRow[i] = Math.Round(rowValue, 2);

        }

    }
}
```